# database dynamic field(custom attribute)

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, custom-attributes

Hi I have a table structure as

**skills**

```
id   
name
```

**users**

```
 id   
 name
```

and many to many relation

**skill_user**

```
skill_id   
user_id
```

different users will have different skill which they will select from skills table thats fine. My problem is that there will be few custom skills(custom attributes) that user will fill in a blank text box. How do i manage this kind of problem please help. I am doing this is php/Laravel/Mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can attach multiple values like this:

```
$user->skill()->attach($request->get('id'),array('customskill' => $request->get('customskill')));
```